How to add multiple comparisons in if else python
I want to know if there is the way to do multiple comrapsions in if else without declaration in for loop
For example i have list of dict:
my_list = [
  {
    'first_name': 'Anna',
    'last_name': 'Frank',
    'id': 1
  },
  {
    'first_name': 'Anna',
    'last_name': 'New',
    'id': 2
  },
  {
    'first_name': 'Anna',
    'last_name': 'Frank',
    'id': 3
  }
]

And i have request filters but i dont know exactly how many of them there will be and i want to filter this list of dict by my request filters
For example user will send me 2 filters: first_name and last_name
request is from Starlette

request_params = request.query_params

new_list = [data for data in my_list if user['first_name'] == 'something there']

user['first_name'] == 'something there' is just for example there
How to make filters in if without declare them in list comprehension and declare them maybe earlier
For example filter by first_name = Anna and last_name == Frank
I want to get this 2 filters or maybe more without every time passing and in if in list comprehension

If you need to do queries like this, then JSON is the wrong answer.  You should use a real database, like SQLite.  This is not what JSON was designed for.

Yeah i know about SQL ofc but i want to know if there is the way to filter like that or its impossible

Just combine the conditions with and or or: if user['first_name'] == 'something there' and user['flast_name'] == 'something else'

If you want to declare the conditions earlier, you can define a function. if func(user) or new_list = list(filter(func, my_list))

If the user sends the filters as a dict, like this:
filters = {
    'first_name': 'Anna',
    'last_name': 'Frank',
}

Then you could check for matching entries like this:
matches = [data for data in my_list if all(data.get(key) == value for key, value in filters.items())]

UPDATE: Use data.get(key) instead of data[key] to allow for filter attributes that are missing from some data items

Oh i like that i will check that

A filter function also works similar to the list comprehension.
filters = {
    'first_name': 'Anna',
    'last_name': 'Frank',
}
func = lambda d : all(d.get(key) == value for key, value in filters.items())

output = list(filter(func, my_list))

